# Please help a newbie with time series prediction

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I am a software developer but trying to figure out if I can learn a pattern in a time series data. My time series data contains two columns. Car number plates and daily indication if they passed a toll bridge. For example

number_plate_1, 14, 15, 20, 25 ...
number_plate_2, 8, 19, 24, 25, 49 ...

Where [14, 15, 49 etc] are days from a set date and they go all they way to 10,000.

There are definitely weekly / month cycles and I need to forecast the next day that a car is most likely to pass the bridge (given its history). Any idea about where to start would be greatly appreciated. I know I lack statistical skills but if you could get me a starting thread, I will try to unravel it with my best.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In relation to your title (but less to your specific problem) you might like to look at a basic book like [Forecasting: principles and practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp) to at least get started with some of the ideas and terminology of some basic methods of time series forecasting. Your specific problem is a little different in form from the kinds of problems typically tackled by those methods but it might help focus what you seek.

Comment: How many unique player numbers do you have?